# What order to give 3D coordinates for openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinates

I am hoping someone can shed some light on this issue for me. If I am given a point (i, j, k), I can make the following cube:

```
     8______K_______7     1 =  i ,  j ,  k
     /|           /|      2 = i+1,  j ,  k
   L/ |         J/ |      3 = i+1, j+1,  k
   /  |H        /  |      4 =  i , j+1,  k
 5/______I_____/6  |G     5 =  i ,  j , k+1
  |   |        |   |      6 = i+1,  j , k+1
  |   |        |   |      7 = i+1, j+1, k+1
 E|  4|________|F__|3     8 =  i , j+1, k+1
  |  /     c   |  /
  | /D         | /B       
  |/___________|/            
  1      A     2
```

where the numbers 1-8 are each of the cube's vertices and the letters A-L are the midpoints of each edge of the cube.

I am trying to implement a marching cube algorithm, but I do not know what order to give the points for each triangular plane I find. For example, if vertex 1 is marked, then I would need to draw a plane from E-D-A. Similarly, if vertex 7 is marked I would need to draw a plane from K-J-G. Is there a rule for the order to give coordinates in 3D space for openGL?

Comment: Have a look at [Paul Bourkes](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/) implementation. Though I seem to recall that the tables had some small errors, but that was many years ago so it's probably been fixed (but you might want to check them against another source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a rule for the order to give coordinates in 3D space for openGL?

OpenGL defines front and back side of a face by the winding of the vertices in screen space. If the vertices of a face in screen space are in counterclock order, the front face is considered visible. Clockwise order => backface. Normals should point into front face direction.

Comment: "OpenGL defines front and back side of a face by the winding of the vertices in screen space." Actually, OpenGL allows _you_ to define what the front and back faces are. That's what [`glFrontFace`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml) does.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Let's put it that way: It's the default setting.